# Failing to deploy nextjs site to netlify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, netlify

I'm experiencing some faulty issues with the build, the plugin on netlify is no longer available for nextjs.

i'm trying to deploy this site to Netlify from Github, it's an update of a different version of the site.

Here's the log below:

```
10:55:16 AM: build-image version: a968751fa4fa5480005f9e300e07554d2cf87d06 (focal)
10:55:16 AM: buildbot version: 8b65fed9bc22a54aead1b50de89fea883757023a
10:55:16 AM: Fetching cached dependencies
10:55:16 AM: Failed to fetch cache, continuing with build
10:55:16 AM: Starting to prepare the repo for build
10:55:16 AM: No cached dependencies found. Cloning fresh repo
10:55:16 AM: git clone --filter=blob:none https://github.com/removed-link/fyi
10:55:16 AM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/master
10:55:17 AM: Parsing package.json dependencies
10:55:18 AM: Starting to install dependencies
10:55:18 AM: Python version set to 3.8
10:55:18 AM: Attempting Ruby version 2.7.2, read from environment
10:55:19 AM: Using Ruby version 2.7.2
10:55:19 AM: Started restoring cached go cache
10:55:19 AM: Finished restoring cached go cache
10:55:19 AM: Installing Go version 1.19.5 (requested 1.19.5)
10:55:24 AM: go version go1.19.5 linux/amd64
10:55:24 AM: Using PHP version 8.0
10:55:25 AM: v16.20.0 is already installed.
10:55:26 AM: Now using node v16.20.0 (npm v8.19.4)
10:55:26 AM: Enabling Node.js Corepack
10:55:26 AM: Started restoring cached build plugins
10:55:26 AM: Finished restoring cached build plugins
10:55:26 AM: Started restoring cached corepack dependencies
10:55:26 AM: Finished restoring cached corepack dependencies
10:55:26 AM: No npm workspaces detected
10:55:26 AM: Started restoring cached node modules
10:55:26 AM: Finished restoring cached node modules
10:55:26 AM: Installing npm packages using npm version 8.19.4
10:55:38 AM: added 330 packages, and audited 331 packages in 12s
10:55:38 AM: 118 packages are looking for funding
10:55:38 AM:   run `npm fund` for details
10:55:38 AM: found 0 vulnerabilities
10:55:38 AM: npm packages installed
10:55:39 AM: Install dependencies script success
10:55:39 AM: Starting build script
10:55:39 AM: Detected 1 framework(s)
10:55:40 AM: "next" at version "13.1.6"
10:55:40 AM: Section completed: initializing
10:55:41 AM: ​
10:55:41 AM:   Netlify Build                                                 
10:55:41 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
10:55:41 AM: ​
10:55:41 AM: ❯ Version
10:55:41 AM:   @netlify/build 29.10.1
10:55:41 AM: ​
10:55:41 AM: ❯ Flags
10:55:41 AM:   baseRelDir: true
10:55:41 AM:   buildId: 6450cfee3a73592fc0dc7f4b
10:55:41 AM:   deployId: 6450cfee3a73592fc0dc7f4d
10:55:41 AM: ​
10:55:41 AM: ❯ Current directory
10:55:41 AM:   /opt/build/repo
10:55:41 AM: ​
10:55:41 AM: ❯ Config file
10:55:41 AM:   No config file was defined: using default values.
10:55:41 AM: ​
10:55:41 AM: ❯ Context
10:55:41 AM:   production
10:55:41 AM: ​
10:55:41 AM:   1. Build command from Netlify app                             
10:55:41 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
10:55:41 AM: ​
10:55:41 AM: $ npm run build
10:55:41 AM: > temp@0.1.0 build
10:55:41 AM: > next build
10:55:42 AM: warn  - You have enabled experimental feature (appDir) in next.config.js.
10:55:42 AM: warn  - Experimental features are not covered by semver, and may cause unexpected or broken application behavior. Use at your own risk.
10:55:42 AM: info  - Thank you for testing `appDir` please leave your feedback at https://nextjs.link/app-feedback
10:55:42 AM: warn  - No build cache found. Please configure build caching for faster rebuilds. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-cache
10:55:42 AM: info  - Creating an optimized production build...
10:55:48 AM: info  - Compiled successfully
10:55:48 AM: info  - Linting and checking validity of types...
10:55:52 AM: 
10:55:52 AM: Failed to compile.
10:55:52 AM: ./components/AboutSection.tsx
10:55:52 AM: 33:34  Error: `'` can be escaped with `&apos;`, `&lsquo;`, `&#39;`, `&rsquo;`.  react/no-unescaped-entities
10:55:52 AM: 37:18  Error: `'` can be escaped with `&apos;`, `&lsquo;`, `&#39;`, `&rsquo;`.  react/no-unescaped-entities
10:55:52 AM: 53:55  Error: `'` can be escaped with `&apos;`, `&lsquo;`, `&#39;`, `&rsquo;`.  react/no-unescaped-entities
10:55:52 AM: ./components/HeroSection.tsx
10:55:52 AM: 27:17  Error: `'` can be escaped with `&apos;`, `&lsquo;`, `&#39;`, `&rsquo;`.  react/no-unescaped-entities
10:55:52 AM: ./components/SlideUp.tsx
10:55:52 AM: 29:6  Warning: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'offset'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
10:55:52 AM: info  - Need to disable some ESLint rules? Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/eslint#disabling-rules
10:55:52 AM: ​
10:55:52 AM:   "build.command" failed                                        
10:55:52 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
10:55:52 AM: ​
10:55:52 AM:   Error message
10:55:52 AM:   Command failed with exit code 1: npm run build
10:55:52 AM: ​
10:55:52 AM:   Error location
10:55:52 AM:   In Build command from Netlify app:
10:55:52 AM:   npm run build
10:55:52 AM: ​
10:55:52 AM:   Resolved config
10:55:52 AM:   build:
10:55:52 AM:     command: npm run build
10:55:52 AM:     commandOrigin: ui
10:55:52 AM:     publish: /opt/build/repo/build
10:55:52 AM:     publishOrigin: ui
10:55:52 AM: Caching artifacts
10:55:52 AM: Started saving node modules
10:55:52 AM: Finished saving node modules
10:55:52 AM: Started saving build plugins
10:55:52 AM: Finished saving build plugins
10:55:52 AM: Started saving corepack cache
10:55:52 AM: Finished saving corepack cache
10:55:52 AM: Started saving pip cache
10:55:52 AM: Finished saving pip cache
10:55:52 AM: Started saving emacs cask dependencies
10:55:52 AM: Finished saving emacs cask dependencies
10:55:52 AM: Started saving maven dependencies
10:55:52 AM: Finished saving maven dependencies
10:55:52 AM: Started saving boot dependencies
10:55:52 AM: Finished saving boot dependencies
10:55:52 AM: Started saving rust rustup cache
10:55:52 AM: Finished saving rust rustup cache
10:55:53 AM: Failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2
10:55:52 AM: Started saving go dependencies
10:55:52 AM: Finished saving go dependencies
10:55:53 AM: Build failed due to a user error: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2
10:55:53 AM: Failing build: Failed to build site
10:55:54 AM: Finished processing build request in 38.141s
```

i tried using different command on the build such as:

```
Cl=" npm run build
```

But did not work either. I also managed to clear the cache and deployed again but that didn't work as work.

Comment: It clearly says that you have some escape issue

**10:55:52 AM: 33:34  Error: `'` can be escaped with `&apos;`, `&lsquo;`, `&#39;`, `&rsquo;`.  react/no-unescaped-entities**

Comment: How do resolve that? @callback